# Can't set line spacing (New to LaTeX)

Tags: line-spacing

I'm trying LaTex for the very first time. I love the system, but have run into a problem (please pardon any newbie mistakes):

```
\emph{Modus ponens}: The form of this argument is:

\hsp if $p$, then $q$.    

\hsp $p$   

\hsp therefore, $q$.
```

Here, `\hsp` is a custom command that adds some horizontal space (`\newcommand{\hsp}{\hspace{2ex}}`). I would like to reduce the line spacing for the last three lines. I have tried `\singlespacing` etc. from the `\setspace` package, but it doesn't seem to work.

Can someone please help me out?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: `\vskip -3pt`, `\vspace{-3pt}` or something similar would help?

Comment: `\hspace{...}` is ignored at the beginning of a line.  if you want to make sure it's *not* ignored, use the starred form: `\hspace*{...}.  regarding the vertical spacing, you might just end all the lines but the last with `\\` and remove the blank lines.  that will treat this as a unit, a single paragraph with explicit line breaks.  alternatively, since it seems like there might be more of these, it's possible a package might exist to format them suitably, or an environment could be defined for the purpose.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One possible solution is to place the argument form inside of a `spacing` environment. This allows you to manipulate the spacing independently of the spacing of the document itself using the `setpsace` package. Another benefit of doing this is that you no longer need to define the `\hsp` command because the `quote` environment indents the text inside of it automatically. Here is an MWE of such a solution:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing

\begin{document}

blah blah blah blah

\emph{Modus ponens}: The form of this argument is:

\begin{quote}
\singlespacing

if $p$, then $q$.    

$p$   

therefore, $q$.
\end{quote}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update:** As @karlkoeller points out, single spacing might not be enough. If single spacing is not enough, you can also place things inside of a `spacing` environment (which is made available by the `setspace` package), instead of a `quote` environment. Then, you can make the spacing even less than single line spacing like so:

```
\begin{spacing}{0.8} % or some smaller number if you would like
if $p$, then $q$.    

$p$   

therefore, $q$.
\end{spacing}
```

This solution will require you to either embed the `spacing` environment inside of a `quote` environment or to reintroduce your `\hsp` command in order to have the form of the argument indented.

Comment: I don't think your answer solves the problem of vertical spacing. The OP said that `\singlespacing` was not enough.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @karlkoeller. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much! It turns out that `quote` would do nicely for now. I'll save the other recipe for future! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this:

```
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1} %More or less. As you wish.
```

Cheers!

Comment: Maybe `\linespread{1}`?